# In css, how to maximize an image's size within a div while keep its aspect-ratio?

Tags: javascript, html, css

For example,

```
<div style="width: 100px; height: 150px">
    <img/>
</div>
```

I want the `img` to be **as large as possible**, but

1. always confined by the `div`, aka, no part of the `img` is outside or overhidden by the `div`.
2. the `img` keeps its aspect-ratio.

It is like keep magnifying the image, and stop as soon as either its height or width hits the border of the `div`.

Is there any convenient way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: You have a few different options if you use [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) - either contain or cover sounds like what you're looking for.

Comment: @lawrence-witt Thank you so much. You want to make it an answer? I will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, using `object-fit: contain` will achieve your desired result. Here is a 200x200px image being contained within a 150x100px div:

```css
.container {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this :

```js
// Get your image tag
var img = document.getElementById("yourImage");

// Set its src
img.src = "https://www.tictactrip.eu/react-app/company-searchHeader-sncf.jpg";

// Wait for it to load
img.addEventListener("load", function() {
    if (img.width > img.height) {
        img.style.width = "100%";
    } else {
        img.style.height = "100%";
    }
});
```

```css
#yourDiv {
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="yourDiv">
    <img id="yourImage"/>
</div>
```

You can eventually use flexboxes to make the image centered in the div.
When you specify only the width/height of an image in CSS, the other dimension will be computed automatically preserving aspect ratio.
Your div must have `position: relative;` for the child image to fit in.

Comment: Thank you, I believe your code is correct, but I cannot accept it as it is not  the simplest way. As lawrence-witt pointed out, `object-fit: contain` is the best way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

you can set the `width` and the `height` of `div` which is parent of `img` and set the `height` and `width` sizes to `100%` to make it fit in the parent `div` and it not overflow no more

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/69/NASA-HS201427a-HubbleUltraDeepField2014-20140603.jpg">
</div>
```

And as you can see in the bellow example parent `div` which has **blue** `border` color have an image inside and the image is fit into try to adjust the `width` and `height` of parent `div` and you will just see your self how the `image` will increase too in order to fit into its parent

Comment: In this case aspect ratio isn't conserved

Comment: Sry I cannot accept this as the aspect ratio isn't conserved

Comment: I guess bellow was what you wanted